# Bind variable while path is not available yet

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am trying to flatten my data according to the firebase good practices, so I tried to create a function like the following:

```
function get(model, id) {
    var path = new Firebase('my/root/url');
    return $firebase(path.child(model+'/'+id)).$asObject();
};
```

Meanwhile in my controller I would like to have something like:

```
$scope.user = get('user', $scope.userId);
```

Where $scope.userId is being set somewhere in the parent controllers. The point is, when the script boots the $scope.userId remains undefined for a while before being set. How can I have $scope.user set as, say, an empty object while id is undefined and then have it synced after the id is set?

I feel the answer would be something like having a promise on the scope so I sync the object when it gets fulfilled, but not so sure yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can watch the `userId` var and fire the function when it has a value.

```
$scope.$watch('userId', function() {
   // Each time userId change this callback will be executed
   if ($scope.userId)
      $scope.user = get('user', $scope.userId) 
})
```

Second solution if you know where the `userId` is setted you can use a custom event:

```
//Execution point where the userId is initalized
$scope.userId = someValue;
$scope.$emit("userid_change",$scope.userId); // Use $broascast instead of $emit if the current scope is father of the other one


// catch the event
$scope.$on("userid_change", function(e, userId) { 
   $scope.user = get('user', userId);
})
```

References:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on